# How do I alert the URL of the page a class isn't found on?

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to turn this code into a loop. Instead of repeating the code within itself, I'd like it to:

1. If ".previous" class exists on the page, grabs its href and apply to $.get
2. Repeat this process until ".previous" class is no longer found on a page
3. Alert the URL of the page the ".previous" class is no longer found on.

```js
var blogPrevious = $(".previous a").attr("href");

if ($(".previous")[0]) {
  $.get(blogPrevious, function(data) {
    var previousFind = $(data).find(".previous a").attr("href");
    $.get(previousFind, function(data) {
      var previousFind2 = $(data).find(".previous a").attr("href");
      alert(previousFind2);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You're almost certainly approaching this problem the wrong way. This could potentially create a huge amount of requests. Can't you do this in the backend some way?

Comment: No, I know this type of request should be done on the back-end, but I only have access to the front-end.

Comment: Hi! You can achieve what you want by using recursion

Comment: @Mr.Turtle If I use a recursive function, would I just turn the code above into a function, and then call that function from within the function?

Comment: Yes. The function will also need a condition to know when it should stop

Comment: @Mr.Turtle Awesome! I took the time to work out such a function and got it to work exactly as I needed it to. I didn't know it was possible to call a function from within that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive what you want using `recursion`. *Recursion is simply when a function calls itself.*

Here is a working example:

```js
var count = 0;
recursiveGet();

function recursiveGet() {
    if(count < 10) {
        count = count + 1;

    $.get("https://httpbin.org/get", function(data){
        console.log("GET #"+count, data);
        recursiveGet();
    })
    } else { console.log("I'm done. I have run 10 times"); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

So assuming that your logic is in order, you can try something like this:

```
var firstElement = $(".previous a").attr("href")
recursiveBlogPrevious( firstElement );

function recursiveBlogPrevious(element) {
    if($(element).length) {
        console.log("The DOM-element exists.", element);

    $.get(element, function(data){
        var foundElement = $(data).find(".previous a").attr("href");
        recursiveBlogPrevious(foundElement);
    })
    } else { console.log("Could not find element."); }
}
```

Just add the intended logic. Good luck!